# Android (ICS) NFC Request and response possible

Tags: android, request, response, nfc

I started working on android (ics) nfc applications. Now I have the scenario of using an nfc smartphone an another nfc device which should communicate with each other.

Not a real problem, but I need a kind of Request/Response scenario. Like the nfc smartphone is held in front to the nfc device and sends an key to it via nfc. The device takes the key and starts communicating with an backend system and after that sends a response back to the nfc smartphone. The smartphone gets the response, handles it, smartphone can’t be removed from device  and we’re done.

But I really need the response.  I did not get this done via the nfc possibilities android ics (beam) is offering.

So therefore my question. Is this somehow possible??
And if yes could somehow explain how? Like using an external library or creating an own?

Comment: It is not entirely clear where your problem is in the scenario you describe. Does the Android Beam UI get in the way, that the user has to tap the screen?

Comment: well the device that has to send the response is not a smartphone and not controlled by a user. the thing is how is it possible with Beam to send an NDEF message and wait for a replay from the receiving device and react on that? as i understood beam it works like a fire and forget.. when a nfc enabled device comes in range, beam sends the defined ndef message and we're done. no possibility to wait for an response from the other device.

Comment: Your statement on Beam is correct. However, you can instruct the user on the screen to hold the phone and wait for the result (if it takes considerable time). The resulting message (sent via Beam) will simply be delivered to the app via an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent.

Comment: the resultung message sent via beam.. i dont really get how this should work.. after the first message from the smartphone to the device is sent, the device reads the message takes the data and does something with it. and then sends it back via beam. how is it done..?? inside my createndefmessage method?? or where should this be implemented??

Comment: I realize now that while reading your question, I was assuming that the "NFC device" was not an Android device. From your last comment I get the impression that may be my assumption is incorrect?

Comment: @steve_t now i am in your issue,can you tell me how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think probably you need the NFC to enable the phone's Wifi-direct then do the two-way data transfer.

Or you may need to put the phone close to the device again, then do the beam again.